# Tomcat MBean Exception on WAR hot deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jmx, mbeans

We have a J2EE web application that runs on Apache Tomcat 7.0.

We use hot deployment for our application updates.

Recently, while trying to deploy a new WAR, it failed with the following exception. I have removed the WAR and tried again, but am getting the same run time exception.

I have already tried the following

1) Tomcat Restart

2) Server Reboot

3) Cleaning up tmp

4) Cleaning up Catalina Cache

What's going wrong?

```
Oct 30, 2017 7:31:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Error registering Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//*.abc.com/g##788,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6448)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//*.abc.com/g##788,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    ... 23 more

Oct 30, 2017 7:31:40 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase register
WARNING: Failed to register object [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[*.abc.com].StandardContext[/g##788]] with name [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[*.abc.com].StandardContext[/g##788]] during component initialisation
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6448)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//*.abc.com/g##788,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    ... 23 more

Oct 30, 2017 7:31:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Error registering Catalina:type=Cache,host=*.abc.com,context=/g##788
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name Catalina:type=Cache,host=*.abc.com,context=/g##788
    ... 20 more

Oct 30, 2017 7:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:411)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository: cannot add mbean for pattern name Catalina:type=Cache,host=*.abc.com,context=/g##788
    ... 20 more

Oct 30, 2017 7:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Oct 30, 2017 7:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Oct 30, 2017 7:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/g##788] startup failed due to previous errors
```